# How to sync up random generation of strings in Python

Tags: python, random

How could I ensure that a randomizing algorithm would produce the same random number for two different programs. I am trying to make a chat program that utilizes a shared password, or key and then uses that key to generate a random string that is only predictable to both programs.

For example

Person A: asd4sa5d8s5s5d5sd
Person B: asd4sa5d8s5s5d5sd

Person A: 2SDASD5545S
Person B: 2SDASD5545S

Comment: Instead of using a random number generator, you could just use a hash algorithm like MD5 or SHA1.

Comment: -1. Don't use non-cryptographic PRNGs when you require any sort of security. Preferably, don't implement your own crypto unless you actually understand what's going on.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a predictable secure string based on a password why not just [use a hash](http://docs.python.org/library/hashlib.html)?  You can encode the hash into a string using [Base64 encoding](http://docs.python.org/library/base64.html).

If you add a [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) to the string before hashing it will make it much harder for people to use a brute force or [rainbow table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) attack to go from the hash back to the password.

```
>>> password = "asd4sa5d8s5s5d5sd"
>>> import hashlib, base64
>>> salt = "mysecretstring"
>>> m = hashlib.md5()
>>> m.update(salt)
>>> m.update(password)
>>> base64.b64encode(m.digest())
'NR6jEKdkVcfcT4pgBnF96A=='
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`random.seed`](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.seed), giving the same value to the function in both clients.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a private instance of Random(). If you just use the random module the usual way, you will get unpredictable results if random numbers are consumed anywhere else in your program

```
from md5 import md5
from random import Random

hsh=md5("passphrase").hexdigest()
seed = long(hsh,16)
myrandom = Random()
myrandom.seed(seed)
print myrandom.randint(0,100)
```